# Getting error creating aws eks cluster using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I need to create AWS EKS module using Terraform. While doing terraform apply I am seeing the below error. Observed the same error while doing terraform destroy.

```
Error making request: Get "https://0550AE24533E68E77491A0730CA351D.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/healthz": read tcp XXX.XXX:55964->XXX.XXX.XXX.79:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
│
│   with module.eks.module.eks.data.http.wait_for_cluster[0],
│   on .terraform\modules\eks.eks\data.tf line 92, in data "http" "wait_for_cluster":
│   92: data "http" "wait_for_cluster" {
```

Below is the terraform AWS EKS module used for creating the EKS cluster.

```
module "eks" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version         = "17.23.0"
  cluster_name    = var.name
  cluster_version = var.version
  subnets         = var.subnets  
  vpc_id = var.eks_vpc_id
 
  node_groups_defaults = {
    root_volume_type = var.root_volume_type
  }

  node_groups = {    
    nodegroupm5l = {
      node_group_name  = var.node_group_name
      instance_types   = [var.node_group_instance_type]
      capacity_type    = var.capacity_type == "SPOT" ? var.capacity_type : null
      desired_capacity = var.node_group_desired_capacity
      max_capacity     = var.node_group_max_capacity
      min_capacity     = var.node_group_min_capacity

      update_config = {
        max_unavailable = var.node_group_update_config_max_available
      }

      additional_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
    }
  }
  map_users = var.eks_map_users
}
resource "aws_eks_addon" "k8s-vpc-cni" {
  cluster_name = module.eks.cluster_id
  addon_name   = "vpc-cni"
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}
```

Please let me know if you need any further details.

```
Adding below details to the query:
```

Below is the Kubernetes provider block

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "eks" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks.token
}
```

Comment: Did you define `required_providers` and `kubernetes` provider blocks?

Comment: Yes. I have defined required_providers and Kubernetes provider blocks. I see the EKS module deployed as well but then seeing the above mentioned error

Comment: Can you add the `kubernetes` provider block to the question?

Comment: I have added Kubernetes provider block to the query above